# How to go to a specific location (by id) in reagent?

Tags: html, anchor, clojurescript, reagent

I have a div tag in http://example.com/bar with the id `foo1`. I have an anchor tag in http://example.com/foo like so: `[:a {:href "http://example.com/bar#foo1"}]`, because I want to jump to the div with `foo1` id in the anchored webpage. But doing this doesn't land me to that div, but simply shows the default behavior of landing to the top of the webpage. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's not really enough information to know. What your describing is HTML, Reagent has no play in this. If I has to guess, I'd guess you aren't rendering the `div` with the id `foo` server side, so `foo` doesn't exist when you visit the page, it's added later. Possibly helpful [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: scrollIntoView does the scrolling, but how can I pass in an id of the location of the element into the new panel that I'm rendering?

Comment: I tried using pushy routes "/foo#bar", but anchor url don't seem to work with pushy.

Answer (score 1):

Anchors (the `a` element) can have a `name` attribute, that is used for the URL fragment (eg. going to a named anchor in a document). See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

If you want HTML element IDs to be used as anchors, maybe you want something like https://github.com/bryanbraun/anchorjs